# Why is the reconnection abnormal after channel inactivation in netty client BootStrap?

Tags: java, netty

**exception**：io.netty.channel.ExtendedClosedChannelException at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.ensureOpen(...)(Unknown Source)。

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rYdgq.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UV6Qu.png)

I would like to be able to establish a new connection, a new channel, after detecting that old Netty's channel is inactivated.

Comment: Please don't post images of code, data, error messages, etc. Copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information please see the Meta FAQ entry https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557

Comment: Also please post entire stack traces, not just the top line. In your question. There is not enough information here for anybody to help you.